# Drawing map with d3js from openstreetmap geojson

Tags: d3.js, geojson

Hy

I'm trying to draw an svg with d3.v3.js from geojson. I fetch the geojson from openstreetmap(my test data: http://pastebin.com/4GQne42i) and try to render it to svg.

My JS code:

```
var path, vis, xy, jdata;

    xy = d3.geo.mercator().translate([0, 0]).scale(200);

    path = d3.geo.path().projection(xy);

    vis = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 960).attr("height", 600);

    //22.json is the name of the file which contains the geojson data
    d3.json("22.json", function(error, json) { 
      jdata = json;
      if(error!=null)
    console.log(error);
      return vis.append("svg:g")
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(json.coordinates)
          .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d", path);
    });
```

And somehow my svg result is this:

```
<svg width="960" height="600">
 <g>
  <path></path>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I know the projection is not good, but I think the svg should have nodes.

What is the problem with my code? Would you post a correct solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is with your [data join](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/):

```
vis.append("g")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(json.coordinates)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
```

This would mean you want one path element for each element in the `json.coordinates` array. Since your test data is a polygon, that would mean one path element for the exterior ring, and then perhaps multiple other path elements for any interior holes, if your data has them. I expect you just want a single path element for the entire polygon.

The second problem is that you’re not passing valid GeoJSON to the [d3.geo.path](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths) instance. Because the data in your data join is `json.coordinates`, you’re just passing an array of coordinates directly to `path`, when you need to pass a GeoJSON geometry object or a feature. (See the [GeoJSON specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html).)

Fortunately both of these problems are easy to fix by eliminating the data join and rendering the full polygon. To add just one path element, just call [selection.append](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append):

```
vis.append("path")
    .datum(json)
    .attr("d", path);
```

Your projection will probably need adjusting (translate and scale), too. You might find the [project to bounding box example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858) useful here.

Comment: one more stupid question, now about projection. 
I adjusted my code, according to your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/RWVeXmK6
It should be good, but my path coordinates are like M2254.42015956094,-5903.748139468257L2254.4261573967847 and the polygond is only 12px*13*px big, however the bounding box is correct.

Comment: You need to use d3.geo.path’s bounds to compute the bounding box in pixel coordinates, not latitude and longitude. (That can be done by d3.geo.bounds, if needed.) Once you have the bounding box in projected coordinates, you can correct the scale and translate to fit the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to do it with D3?

I would suggest to go with more map oriented libraries like:

- [polymaps](http://polymaps.org/)
- [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)

Leaflet vector layer has support for GeoJSON and its size is quite compact.

Open Layers is also an option but it's size is quite big.

Here is an example how I have used Leaflet + GeoJSON to display suburb shape http://www.geolocation.ws/s/6798/en